# Convert a properly formatted string to data frame

Tags: r

I have

```
x<-"1, A | 2, B | 10, C "
```

`x` is always this way formatted, `|` denotes a new row and the first value is the `variable1`, the second value is `variable2`.

I would like to convert it to a data.frame

```
  variable1 variable2
1         1         A
2         2         B
3        10         C
```

I haven't found any package that can understand the escape character `|`

How can I convert it to `data.frame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `read.table` from `base R` to read the string into two columns after replacing the `|` with `\n`

```
read.table(text = gsub("|", "\n", x, fixed = TRUE), sep=",", 
    header = FALSE, col.names = c("variable1", "variable2"), strip.white = TRUE )
```

-output

```
 variable1 variable2
1         1        A 
2         2        B 
3        10        C
```

---

Or use `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fread(gsub("|", "\n", x, fixed = TRUE), col.names = c("variable1", "variable2"))
   variable1 variable2
1:         1         A
2:         2         B
3:        10         C
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` - `separate_rows` to split the column and then create two columns with `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(x = trimws(x)) %>% 
  separate_rows(x, sep = "\\s*\\|\\s*") %>%
  separate(x, into = c("variable1", "variable2"), sep=",\\s+", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  variable1 variable2
      <int> <chr>    
1         1 A        
2         2 B        
3        10 C
```

Comment: What a fantastic answer. Thank you very much. I've checked the first answer. Is it possible to modify so that it removes the whitespace arround the values of variable2?

Comment: @ECII Thanks.  I forgot to add the `strip.white` earlier. Updated

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `scan()`.

```
x <- "1, A | 2, B | 10, C "

do.call(rbind.data.frame,
        strsplit(scan(text=x, what="A", sep='|', quiet=T, strip.white=T), ', ')) |>
  setNames(c('variable1', 'variable2'))
#   variable1 variable2
# 1         1         A
# 2         2         B
# 3        10         C
```

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`.